How to get current network I/O stats from docker instead of cumulative stats?
I can use sudo docker stats to get stats about IO, memory, CPU, and network. But, they are cumulative, whereas I'd like current throughput rates. How can I make this happen?

see iftop and other network interfaces monitoring utilities.
